# Issue printing a combination of a string with an unpacked list using an f string

Tags: python

- I have a string (K in this case)
- I have a list containing numbers, I want to print these numbers to follow "K", separated by a comma.

The command I used to print is:

```
print(f'K {*list, sep = ","}')
```

The error I got is:

```
print(f' K {*list, sep = ", "} ')
          ^
SyntaxError: f-string: expecting '}'
```

What's wrong with my command?

I also tried the join command (",".join(list)), but the error I got there seemed to indicate that there were issues when the list is empty or only contains one element.

Comment: Don't use `list` as a variable name.  Doing so masks the builtin `list`.  That having been said, provide a sample value for your list variable, including the data types of its elements.  And show exactly what output you want for those values.

Comment: What do you think `sep=` is doing there? You're not calling anything.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a comma delimited string from your list you'd use `str.join` which you can do within your f-string

```
>>> data = ['some','words','here']
>>> print(f'K {",".join(data)}')
K some,words,here
```

Similarly if the list is not of string types you can convert them using a generator expression

```
>>> data = [1,2,3]
>>> print(f'K {",".join(str(i) for i in data)}')
K 1,2,3
```